# How to stop Chrome from warning me when opening many tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome I have a bookmark folder which contains many bookmarks to web-comics. Every day I right click on that folder and select "Open all bookmarks in new window." That makes it very easy to tab through all the comics and then close the window when I'm done reading.

The annoying thing is that every time I open the window, Chrome asks me "Are you sure you want to open 18 tabs?"

Yes, I am sure. This dialog box is just annoying and wasting my time. Is there a way to get it so the default is always yes, and the dialog box never appears?

Comment: The limit is 15 tabs, so you may want to try reducing your number of links or divide them into separate folders. Or save the tabs are URL shortcuts in a folder in your computer, and just open them in Chrome. You could also put them in a batch file with the `start` command: `start "" "www.microsoft.com"`

Comment: I liked that option it saved me time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer or lack thereof currently: [Google Chrome Forum](http://www.google.co.nz/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=481ffe082456d402&hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

There is a feature request on [Chromium's project page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117692) from 2012. The title is:

> Don't warn repeatedly when opening 15+ bookmarks in one action

It was closed in 2014 with the status "**WontFix**" which means there won't be a built-in way to disable this warning.

---

As an alternative you could use [Neater Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neater-bookmarks/ofgjggbjanlhbgaemjbkiegeebmccifi/related?hl=en). You have to disable this option after installation

[image]

Bulk opening by middle-click or right-click+context menu on a folder works. No warning will be displayed

Comment: Thank you very much! I already use Neater Bookmarks, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you consider different way of daily workflow? Instead of opening all the bookmarks, cannot you just set up option "Restore all opened tabs" in Chrome? So every day you will just continue from the state you left yesterday and you don't have to open all bookmarks.

Comment: The question describes wanting a set of tabs opened only temporarily and when desired.  Nixda's answer provides a solution, so a workaround that doesn't really do what the question asked doesn't seem like a necessary fallback.  With a little more rep, this kind of alternative could be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Neater Bookmarks, it worked, but if you open your tabs from the bookmarks bar, the warning still displays.

I find a workaround using Autohotkey (https://autohotkey.com/). You'll need to install it first, but it's a great, great free tool and I've used it for many years.

After you've installed Autohotkey, put the following in a script named mbutton.ahk:

~MButton::Send, {Enter}

Then run mbutton.ahk

Now, open a book mark folder by middle click, the warning shoud be dismissed automatically.

If the one line script does not work, try adding a time delay, like:

~MButton::
{
Sleep, 100
Send, {Enter}
}

Answer (score 0):

Worse than just getting a notification, chrome just closes the notification and does nothing after clicking "yes"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcfIV.jpg)

Comment: fwiw this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Sorry. You're right. How can I correct that? Oh, never mind, I can NOT post a comment because I don't have enough points, so the only way for me to "reply" is through an answer, that's why I did it.